# Dummy output in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

I brought a laptop named "Infinix X1 Slim" with pre-installed Windows 11. I've removed Windows 11 and installed Ubuntu 18.04. From then, there's no audio in my laptop. Then I upgraded to 20.04 still the problem persists.

Comment: Trying to use an old release on new hardware is a bad idea. Try 22.04 or 22.10. It is also advisable to post relevant hardware specs in case there is a hardware detection problem.

Comment: Worst case may be that the Linux kernel and sound system does not support your audio hardware. Trying the newest available kernel for Ubuntu may resolve the issue. Otherwise, you may need to build the kernel module for your audio hardware yourself - assuming the necessary source code is available. Further help may be advise once details on the audio hardware are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal.
Type alsamixer and press the Enter key. You will see the following output in your terminal.
Select your correct sound card by pressing F6.
Use the left and right arrow keys to select a volume control. The currently selected item is shown in red.
Use the up and down arrow keys to increase and decrease volume levels for each control.
When a mixer control is muted, “MM” appears below the volume bar. Note that a bar can be 100% full but still be muted, so do check for this. You can unmute a control by pressing the m key. This changes “MM” to “OO.”